# Javascript URL string adding %20 (space) after running grunt

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, gruntjs

**TLDR;**

**FIXED AS FOLLOWS**

```
selectedValue = selectedValue.replace(/\s+/g, '')
```

Thanks to: ***Richard Macarthy*** and ***Aaron Digulla*** for the answer, which led me down the poath to the correct answer.

Just tp be clear, it seems Grunt was adding this whitespace for some reason. The fix is very simple...

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have an JSON request, which get the contents of a JSON file to be used for data visualisations using d3.js.

This all works fine locally, but when I run grunt build the URL string gets an `%20` injected into it from nowhere...

Here is how the string looks before I run Grunt:

```
d3.json("json/wards-info/"+selectedValue+"-wards-data.json", function(error, newDatas) {
    newData = newDatas;
    newWardsData = newWardsDatas;
    drawMap(newData, newWardsData);
});
```

Which computes to:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/json/wards-info/liverpool-ward-data.json
```

After I run Grunt build the computed URL string changes to:

```
http://localhost:8080/dist/json/wards-info/liverpool%20-ward-data.json
```

As you can see, it appears to be adding `%20` between `liverpool-ward`

Is this because of grunt, or due to something else?

Comment: Well %20 is a whitespace so is there a whitespace in the variable?

Comment: Where does `selectedValue` come from?  It's probably that value that's gaining the extra space/`%20`. Is it generated by grunt somewhere?

Comment: @epascarello There is no whitespace in selectValue

Comment: @JamesThorpe It comes from an input field, there is no whitespace in the string, I have checked the string before making the request and there is not a space...

Comment: Are you positive it is not there? `console.log(escape(selectedValue));` And does the `s` get dropped too?

Comment: @epascarello Yes I am sure there is no white space. The s does not get dropped I just didn;t add it in. I have added it now.

Comment: Just dropped back in to this question to see how it was going - I would note that you've applied a sticking plaster, rather than a fix, without completely understanding _why_ it was behaving this way.  I would continue to be concerned about the _why_, just in case it crops up again in an unexpected way.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, I absolutely agree, it must be something with one of the Grunt tasks i am running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%20` usually represents a space in HTML URL Encoding, try to make sure there are no spaces in your output.

You can use something like this to help:

`string.replace(/ /g,'')` to strip the white spaces out.  Where string is your URL.

Either that or try this:

`.replace(/%20/g,'')`

Comment: But there are no white spaces. I have already tried the above... Could I be a Grunt issue?

Comment: It appears that something is calling `encodeURI()` on your string and changing a space into `%20` can you try `.replace(/%20/g,'')`?  I'm not 100% sure though, sorry.

Comment: I have fixed it now, I used a similar method to what you suggested. The particular fix for me was: selectedValue = selectedValue.replace(/\s+/g, '');

Answer (score 3):

Simply check your selectedValue value. There is a space before `-` character. Either remove it, or call trim before using it.

Should solve your problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure there should be one on `selectedValue` try trimming it before....

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for. There is not whitespace in selectedValue so calling trim() is useless

Comment: So when you try to log into console "json/wards-info/"+selectedValue+"-wards-data.json" you got no space, but after grunt runs over it, it has one?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because of something else. `%20` is added because of URL escaping rules (which `d3.json()` probably applies; Grunt shouldn't have an effect here) but what it means is that `selectedValue` ends with a space character. I've read in your comments that you're 100% sure that there isn't one but if that was true, then there wouldn't be a `%20` in the URL. Computers don't add things just for fun, there is always a reason.

So my suggestion is to debug the code as it runs to see what the variable contains, then search your whole code base for `-wards-data.json` (because maybe there is a second place in the code that you forgot about).

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to tell us more about the Grunt config (are you compressing scripts, obfuscating? Do you have plugins installed?) Also show us the code which Grunt generates out of your input.

Comment: I understand what the %20 implies. but there is not an spaces after selectedValue or within the URL string. Did you see that it is working fine locally, before running grunt? It works fine from the app folder, but the dist folder adds the space after selectedValue.

Comment: I saw what you wrote but that doesn't add up. How does Grunt change the code in the app folder? Did you check that code? Does it look correct? Did you debug it?

Comment: Hi, yes checked and debugged, there are no spaces and the string is only used in 2 places, both have no spaces. When I log "json/wards-info/"+selectedValue+"-wards-data.json" from app folder I get "json/liverpool-wards.json" but when I run from the dist folder I get "json/liverpool -wards.json"

Comment: Thanks for your advide, the fix ended up being: selectedValue = selectedValue.replace(/\s+/g, '')